# Retrieving an Array with Axios in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

i am making an Axios request to one of my controller functions which is going into my DB and getting all the suppliers information however when it is return to my VUE file there is no data

This is my request:

```
mounted(){
            axios.get('/product/'+ this.url + '/suppliers/info').then(response=>console.log(response.data));

        },
```

and this is my controller function

```
public function getSuppliers($product){

        $suppliers = $this->supplier->getAll();

        return response()->json($suppliers);
    }
```

When i dd out $suppliers in the controller it has all the data so i know it has been success retrieved from the DB but when i console log it out once it has been return to VUE the data is gone.

This is what i see if i just console log response:-
[image]

I can see it is return all the arrays which should be there but none of them have any data in? what am i doing wrong?

This is a snippet of $suppliers when i DD it in the controller:
[image]

Image of the request header from network:-
[image]

getAll function :-

```
public function getAll()
{
    return $this->buildEntities($this->data->orderBy('name')->get());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$suppliers` doesn't seems an array, but a eloquent model. so try this:

```
return response()->json(["suppliers"=>$suppliers], 200);
```

And see in `response.data.suppliers`

** EDIT **

The problem can be the function buildEntity.
try to

```
$this->data->orderBy('name')->get()
```

Comment: Still getting an empty array, also your right it is an eloquent model (sorry im a frontend guy)

Comment: if you print $suppliers->toArray() what return?

Comment: do you mean add dd($suppliers->toArray()); to controller? if so i just get an error saying "Call to a member function toArray() on array"

Comment: ok, yes, your problem remain a $suplliers array because if with fake array it work, the problem is this. try to make a more simple query, like Suppliers::all() for test.